# How to process all events of Observable in one thread, but get the latest value available in another thread in Rxjava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I am using RxJava2 in Android and I have the below problem, but it's not specific to Android.

I have a `PublishSubject` to push all my events. I call `publishSubject.onNext()` in multiple parts of my code based on different events. But I have a central place in my code where I subscribe to these events. The below is the subscription code:

```
publishSubject
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map(
        // each computation takes about 10ms
        // Do some computation and return a `computation` object
    )
    .observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        // take the `computation` object and draw on screen
        // each drawing takes about 100ms
    );
```

Now, in the above case, if I call `publishSubject.onNext()` 100 times, then `computation` will be done 100 times and drawing on screen will be done 100 times.

The thing is I care about the 100 times computation. Every event has to be computed. But not every computed object needs to be drawn.

When the 1st `computation` object is being drawn on screen it takes 100ms to draw in MAIN thread, but by that time 10 new `computation` objects are generated in COMPUTATION thread.  So the 2nd time I draw on the screen I don't want to draw the 2nd `computation` object, but rather the latest `computation` object available for me (probably the 11th computation object).

In short, I am looking for a way to do all computation all the time, but draw on screen only the latest computation object available at that time.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this?

```
publishSubject
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(...)
.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
.observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(...);
```

This will make sure that the computation actually happens, but the subscription will not receive items that are too far back in time.

Comment: Almost. You have to limit the prefetch on `observeOn(mainThread(), false, 1)` otherwise the internal buffer will still likely store the intermediate values.

Comment: @akarnokd +1
@Tassos This didn't fully solve my problem, but thanks for pointing me towards `Flowable`. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @akarnokd Indeed, thanks for pointing that out. Initially I was placing `toFlowable` pas the second scheduler switch, but then I though of all those useless context switches...